# PDF File downloads incorrectly(corrupted ) in browser using express.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

i am using following code snippet to download pdf and other types of file.

```
exports.getFile = function(req , res , next){
  var file = req.params.file
    , path = 'login/files/'+file;
  res.download(path);
};
```

text file is downloaded correctly but pdf is not downloading correctly(it download but corrupted pdf file).i have seen pdf file is uploaded correctly to server(it is not corrupted on server.but downloading does it corrupt). i am unable to figure out this problem. please suggest me how to figure out this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to set `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');` I think.

Comment: i have done this.but did not resolve this issue.

Comment: Things you can try to reproduce the issue without PDF file: transmit text file equal in length and/or use binary file comparison to check differences. Please provide a complete example -- it's not clear what is `next` for and how getFile is invoked?

Comment: I'm having similar issues too by simply linking to the pdf. Some pdfs work, but some don't.

Comment: Did it get compressed during upload? To identify this as the cause, take a copy of the downloaded file, then manually change the file extension to something like .gz. Then try opening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set response header like :

```
exports.getFile = function(req , res , next){
  var file = req.params.file
    , path = 'login/files/'+file;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.download(path);
};
```